# Java 7 64 bit on windows 7: how to switch java versions

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit

I need to switch from the installed java 7 at 64bit to the installed java 6 on my Windows 7 64bit OS but the usual procedure doesn't works.
I tried to change the JAVA_HOME environment variable but when I type java -version, the system replies Java 7...
How can I switch from different java versions?

Thank you.

Comment: Try with complete path to java.exe.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to switch the path environment variable too, to point before to the JRE bin directory. Also, I think modern versions of java place a copy of "java.exe" in the system32 directory of Windows, you'll need to remove them (or rename them, if you want to keep them as backups).

Comment: Thank you! I renamed the java.exe on system32 folder and It works!

Comment: No problem, I recently upgraded to Windows 7 64 both at home and at work,  and I ran into the problems you describe.

Comment: I had the reversed problem: I wanted java 7 but it would only run java 6. You solved my problem too, I removed the java.exe in system32. Thanks!

Comment: that's it, there was files in system32 when I rennamed them its OK.
NB: I use Windows 7 (32), java 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6

Comment: Gosh, thanks for System32 hint. I've gone almost mad trying to get rid of Java 7 version trough PATH variable :D

Comment: thought of unistalling java7 before i saw this post. thanks it saved a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

`JAVA_HOME` is not used by java.exe.

Make sure to have the path of the Java 6 JRE's `bin` directory in the PATH environment variable, before the Java 7 JRE's one, and before windows system directory (system32).

Or you can use the full path of the java command:

```
c:\java6\bin\java com.foo.bar.Main
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows relies on `PATH` environment variable and not `JAVA_HOME` to lookup executables including the Java application launcher java.exe. While the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable may be used in the `PATH` environment variable, it need not be the case, so you must modify the `PATH` environment variable to use `JAVA_HOME` or the new Java 6 installation home.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java supports a "-version" command line option. You can use this to select a specific version to run, e.g.:

`java -version:1.7 -jar [path to jar file]`
will run a jar application in java 1.7, if it is installed.

See Oracle's documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html